# How to capture changes to y1 via y1summary?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

world,

I want to get more familiar with the Tensorboard API.

I studied the script I found here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/code/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py

It runs well on my laptop.

Much of it makes sense to me.

So, I wrote a simple tensorflow demo:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

with tf.name_scope('scope0'):
  y1 = tf.Variable(1.1)
  # I should intialize:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  tf.scalar_summary('y1summary', y1)

merged       = tf.merge_all_summaries()
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/tb4',sess.graph)
step_i       = 0

summary,out1 = sess.run([merged,y1])
train_writer.add_summary(summary, step_i)

step_i += 1
y1   = y1 - 1.1
summary,out1 = sess.run([merged,y1])
train_writer.add_summary(summary, step_i)

step_i += 1
y1   = y1 + 2.1
summary,out1 = sess.run([merged,y1])
train_writer.add_summary(summary, step_i)

train_writer.close()
```

So, I run the above script with this shell command:

```
python tensorboard_demo4.py
```

And it runs with no error.

Next I run Tensorboard:

```
tensorboard --log=/tmp/tb4
```

It runs with no error.

But when I look at the events tab,
Tensorboard shows a constant value for y1summary.

[image: tensorboard y1summary]

So, I do not understand something fundamental about Tensorboard.

How to enhance the above script so that Tensorboard displays changes to y1 via y1summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

with tf.name_scope('scope0'):
  y1 = tf.Variable(1.1)
  # I should intialize:
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  tf.scalar_summary('y1summary', y1)

merged       = tf.merge_all_summaries()
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/tb4',sess.graph)
step_i       = 0

summary,out1 = sess.run([merged,y1])
train_writer.add_summary(summary, step_i)

step_i += 1
sess.run(y1.assign(y1 - 1.1))
summary,out1 = sess.run([merged,y1])
train_writer.add_summary(summary, step_i)

step_i += 1
sess.run(y1.assign(y1 + 2.1))
summary,out1 = sess.run([merged,y1])
train_writer.add_summary(summary, step_i)

train_writer.close()
```

Basically, you need to assign the new value to the variable(y1 in this case) you are capturing the summary of.